# SQL Condition not being picked up - left outer join

Tags: sql, left-join, conditional-statements, outer-join

Below, I have an SQL select statement, but I'm having some issues with one of the conditions being picked up. Is there another way I can arrange this statement so that the condition is picked up ?

Condition not being picked up:

```
(NSTR_UI_OBJ.dte_ui_obj_end is NULL or (NSTR_UI_OBJ.dte_ui_obj_end >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00'))
```

Full statement:

```
SELECT NSTR_UI_OBJ.NAM_UI_OBJ
      ,CDE_UI_OBJ_TYP
      ,DES_UI_OBJ_LNG
      ,NVL(NSTR_UI_OBJ_CNTC.CDE_NSTR_CNTC_TYP,'')
      ,NVL(NSTR_CNTC_COMM.TXT_COMM_VALUE,'') 
FROM NSTR_UI_OBJ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN NSTR_UI_OBJ_CNTC ON NSTR_UI_OBJ_CNTC.ID_UI_OBJ = NSTR_UI_OBJ.ID_UI_OBJ 
                                AND (NSTR_UI_OBJ.dte_ui_obj_end is NULL 
                                      or (NSTR_UI_OBJ.dte_ui_obj_end >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00')
                                     )
LEFT OUTER JOIN NSTR_CNTC_COMM    ON  NSTR_UI_OBJ_CNTC.ID_NSTR_CNTC = NSTR_CNTC_COMM.ID_NSTR_CNTC
ORDER BY CDE_UI_OBJ_TYP,NSTR_UI_OBJ.NAM_UI_OBJ
```

Comment: "picked up"? Can you explain what you mean in more detail? Input/output/expected would be helpful.

Comment: so right now that statement lists all records and is ignoring what the DTE_UI_OBJ_END value is. I would like the statement to output only records with a DTE_UI_OBJ_END of NULL or a date greater than the current date.

Answer (score 1):

Put the condition in a `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT NSTR_UI_OBJ.NAM_UI_OBJ, CDE_UI_OBJ_TYP, DES_UI_OBJ_LNG, NVL(NSTR_UI_OBJ_CNTC.CDE_NSTR_CNTC_TYP, ''), NVL(NSTR_CNTC_COMM.TXT_COMM_VALUE, '')
FROM NSTR_UI_OBJ
LEFT OUTER JOIN NSTR_UI_OBJ_CNTC ON NSTR_UI_OBJ_CNTC.ID_UI_OBJ = NSTR_UI_OBJ.ID_UI_OBJ
LEFT OUTER JOIN NSTR_CNTC_COMM ON NSTR_UI_OBJ_CNTC.ID_NSTR_CNTC = NSTR_CNTC_COMM.ID_NSTR_CNTC
WHERE NSTR_UI_OBJ.dte_ui_obj_end IS NULL
    OR (NSTR_UI_OBJ.dte_ui_obj_end >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00')
ORDER BY CDE_UI_OBJ_TYP, NSTR_UI_OBJ.NAM_UI_OBJ
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked since someone decided to downvote my answer without leaving a comment.

Comment: @jdoyle0116 please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or upvote my answer since it worked for you and might help others.